# JavaFX / how to load/populate values at start up?

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

I started working with JavaFX just today and already need some advise. I load the `applicaton.fxml` (created with Oracle SceneBuiler) using the FXMLLoader in the `start(Stage ...)` method of the MainApplication (which has an ApplicationController specified in my `application.fxml` file).

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" disable="false" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="800.0" styleClass="theme" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="app.AppController">
...more code here...
<ComboBox id="cmb_locations" fx:id="cmb_locations">
    <items>
        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
            <String fx:value="Item 1" />
            <String fx:value="Item 2" />
            <String fx:value="Item 3" />
        </FXCollections>
    </items>
</ComboBox>
```

Now, I have a `ComboBox` in the `applicaton.fxml`, which has three items (the default items). What I need is to populate that `ComboBox` during the startup with my own values. Does anyone know how to achieve that and where to put the relevant code snippets (`app.AppController` or something similar)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have some controller for you fxml file. There you have access to your ComboBox. You could put this code to setup list of elements (probably in initialize() method):

If you don't really want to edit your fxml file you can just clear the list first with `cmb_locations.getItems().clear();` before you setup new list.

```
public class ApplicationController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    ComboBox cmb_locations;
    ...
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        ...
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Item A");
        list.add("Item B");
        list.add("Item C");
        ObservableList obList = FXCollections.observableList(list);
        cmb_locations.getItems().clear();
        cmb_locations.setItems(obList);
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: btw. what is the difference between the `public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)` and the (by the SceneBuilder created) `void initialize()` method?

Comment: I am using netbeans and when I create the fxml with controller from pattern it generates `public` access for this method. I have this method as `public` in Initializable interface (javafx ver 2.2.25). So not sure why SB goes for package-private.

Comment: @nyyrikki `public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)` is old version. now you just have to write `void initialize();` new version.

Answer (score 4):

Start by removing the default values on the FXML "Item 1" "Item 2" ...
just to have

```
<FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
    </FXCollections>
```

and on your controller if you want retrieve your combobox  you have to inject it by doing

```
@FXML
ComboBox cmb_locations

public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resource) {
//here populate your combobox
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your controller, you implement the Initializable interface.
Then in initialize method, you just add your code to load your combo box.